# How to delete a label from tkinter after a countdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, label

I am trying to create a ten-second countdown that removes itself after it reaches zero. How and where do I put code to remove the label?

I have experimented with `label.destroy()` and `label.forget()`, but they do not work, creating an error message, most likely because they do not exist.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def countdown(count):
    label['text'] = count
    if count > 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)
    elif count == 0:
        label['text'] = 'Time Expired'

label = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48))
label.place(x=132, y=102)
countdown(10)
label.pack_forget()
```

I was hoping for the program to delete the label after it finished its task. However, it counts down, but does not remove itself.

Comment: `labelname.destroy()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see "Time expired" for 1 sec and then hide the label try this code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
def countdown(count, label):
    label['text'] = count
    if count > 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
    elif count == 0:
        label['text'] = 'Time \nExpired'
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1, label)
    elif count < 0:
        label.destroy()

label = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48))
label.place(x=132, y=102)
countdown(10, label)
root.mainloop()
```

The main issue is that you do not wait for countdown function to finish execution cycle before hiding the label; One solution is that hiding instruction to be moved inside countdown function and executed in the last cycle.

Comment: The definition code for the `countdown()` requires two arguments, meaning that the code `countdown(10)` will not work, as it only has 1 argument. Therefore, an error message shows, displaying "TypeError: countdown() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'"

Answer (score 2):

Call `destroy` or `pack_forget` inside the `countdown` function not after it:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def countdown(count):
    label['text'] = count
    if count > 0:
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)
    elif count == 0:
        label['text'] = 'Time \nExpired'
        label.pack_forget()  # or label.destroy()


label = Label(root, anchor=CENTER, font=('Calibri', 48))
label.place(x=132, y=102)
label.pack()
countdown(10)
root.mainloop()
```